# How to retrieve values from a column called "object_id" in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I need to access a legacy relational database via ActiveRecord and that database uses a column named "object_id" as a primary key in a table. Most things work but when I try specify a custom SQL query for an association (see below) ActiveRecord respectively the Ruby interpreter always retrieves the object_id of the Ruby base "Object" instead of the column value from the database.

I defined the following SQL query in a has_many declaration:

> :finder_sql => "SELECT * FROM t_object WHERE object_id IN (SELECT end_object_id FROM t_object, t_connector WHERE t_object.object_id = #{object_id} AND start_object_id = #{object_id})

I already tried to solve it by working with an alias:

> alias_attribute :my_oid, :object_id

and using "my_oid" in the SQL query. But I got the following error message:

> NameError: undefined local variable or method `my_oid' for EaTObject(Table doesn't exist):Class

I also defined a method which returns the value of read_attribute("object_id") and put the method name into the SQL query instead of "object_id" but when the class was loaded I got the error message that that method name is not a column name in the database table.

Is there any solution to access a column called "object_id"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is `self[:object_id]`, but if you are getting "Table doesn't exist", then maybe there is something else wrong?

Edit:
Try this:

```
:finder_sql => 'SELECT * FROM t_object WHERE object_id IN (SELECT end_object_id FROM t_object, t_connector WHERE t_object.object_id = #{id} AND start_object_id = #{id})'
```

**NB!** single quotes.

Comment: When I put self[:object_id] into the :finder_sql query I get the same error message. I tried the SQL query directly in the database with a concrete value for the object_id and it worked. The error message is only there when I don't put a column name into #{}.

Comment: of what type are the `object_id` and `start_object_id`?

Comment: Actually, I think you need to use `#{id}` instead of `object_id` and it will work. Try it

Comment: Thanks, the single quotes are the solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this method:

```
read_attribute(:object_id)
```

The link in documentation :

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Read.html#method-i-read_attribute

So if you want access to your object_id column whan you call oid you need delete your alias and define the oid method

```
def oid
  read_attribute(:object_id)
end
```

Comment: When I use #{read_attribute(:object_id)} in :finder_sql I get the error "NoMethodError: undefined method `read_attribute' for EaTObject(Table doesn't exist):Class".

Comment: it seems you haven't this table in your database

Comment: I tried the SQL query directly in the database with a concrete value for the object_id and it worked. The error message is only there when I don't put a column name into #{}.

Comment: I really don't understand your case. We need more code to understand. Update your question or ask another

Comment: You don't need other stuf than read_attributes. So delete your alias and use only read_attributes(:object_id) in your oid methode

Answer (score 0):

You may use `t_object.object_id` in your SQL to specify object_id field, or you may alias your t_object table, e.g.

```
:finder_sql => "SELECT * FROM t_object AS t WHERE t.object_id IN..."
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but it didn't work. In my opinion the problem is #{object_id} in the SQL query because this calls the inherited method object_id of the Ruby class "Object" and not the method generated by ActiveRecord::Base. I also could not replace #{object_id} by something else because ActiveRecord wants a column name in :finder_sql.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute a select like I had to, I'd suggest using an alias for the column name to get it working as expected.
sql selects the unique id number for the object within the database, if you want to select the value instead, you can do using this

```
SELECT books.object_id as obj_id FROM books
```